# freemarker with spring - how to bind global data to a template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I want to create a small project with spring mvc and freemarker.

I have created a small template and a layout:

Template:

```
<#import "layout/defaultLayout.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.myLayout>
  <div><h1>Hello Dude</h1></div>
</@layout.myLayout>
```

Layout:

```
<#macro myLayout>
  <html>
    <body>
            <!-- menu -->

            <!-- content -->
            <#nested/>
    </body>
  </html>
</#macro>
```

My question now:
How could I create a dynamic value(perhaps bean data)?
I do not want to add the data in each controller action.
What is a good solution to put such data to a complete layout that is not specific to a controller action?

Comment: Have you considered "shared variables" (http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_sharedvariables.html)? In Spring's `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory` they call it "freemarkerVariables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution.
I need to use a ControllerAdvice annotation and a ModelAttribute annotation like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class LayoutMenu {
    @ModelAttribute("foo")
    public String initMenu() {
        return "Hello Bar";
    }
}
```

This solves my problem.